# How to see print statements using pytest-watch?

Tags: python, logging, pytest

While debuging my python code, I'm trying to see the print statements while running the tests.
If I run `pytest -s` or `pytest --capture=no` I can see my prints as expected but when I try to pass the option to `ptw` I get an error and the tests don't run.

Is there anyway I could see the prints while using `ptw`?

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked for me was creating a pytest config file and adding the option to `addopts =`. By doing that, the ptw will pick up the configuration.

Any option that you would pass to `pytest` command line you can pass on this addopts.

My file looks like this:

```
[pytest]
addopts = --capture=no
testpaths = tests
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another option which would be to use --runner.
With this, you can even include which function you want to run, which is unavailable with `ptw`.

`ptw --runner "pytest -k my_test_func --capture=no"`